# Infowindow cut off at the top

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Here is the code to demo the issue I noticed.

> [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyberram/NLzqf/) <

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <style type='text/css'>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    p,h4 {
        margin:0;
    }
    #map-canvas{
        width:425px;
        height:300px;
        margin:1em;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-38.06794990,145.30192430);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var contentString = '<div style="width:300px;"><H4>Heading</H4><P><B>Address:</B> Community Centre 51L The Strand, Narre Warren South 3805</P></div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Food Waste and Organics workshop'
    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
//]]>  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The infowindow opens fine, when its opened with the click event. But if its done on window load event, it doesn't align the infowindow properly in the map area and the top part of the infowindow is cut off. Even increasing the height of the map div doesn't seem to help.

Thanks,
Kumar.

Comment: If you want `infoWindow` to be in center, then increase the width of `map-canvas`.  Incase if you don't want to increase the size, then use `PanTo` option in google maps.

Comment: Sorry. Increasing the width/height of the `map-canvas` didn't really help. It still cuts of the infowindow at the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Google maps Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) for panTo().

```
map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(lat + your panDownValue, lon));
```

This is just a quick fix for your question.

[**JSFIDDLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/VwMyv/1/)

**EDIT:** I tried to trigger the marker's "click" event and it is working fine.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
      google.maps.event.trigger(marker,'click');
 });
```

`idle` Event fired when the map becomes idle after panning or zooming.

[**JSFIDDLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/VwMyv/2/)

Comment: I know about the panTo function. I see the fix you gave, you have added 6 to the latitude for it to work. How did you arrive at that number? Lets consider a use case where the map when loaded can be in various zoom level. How would you determine the coordinates for the panTo method then. My point is, the infowindow is positioned properly, when triggered inside a click event. But it doesn't work as  expected in a window load event. I believe its a bug in google maps api.

Comment: @Kumar I got your point, then I would suggest you to trigger the marker's "click" event.  I have updated my answer.